# Session Façade in a Client-Server Application

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, architectural-patterns

In the J2EE Pattern Session Façade - that the "Core J2EE Patterns - Best Practices and Design Strategies" book says:

> Use a Session Façade to encapsulate business-tier components and expose a coarse-grained service to remote clients. Clients access a Session Façade instead of accessing business components directly.

I want to know what it means with remote clients? Cause i'm creating a client server application where the client is an android app and the server is a java server.
Is Session Façade what i need to expose to the client (the android app) the API that is necessary for the communication between them two?

Thanks.

Comment: This question belongs on a code architecture forum, as it will become a discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Diagram]

A remote client can be anything - Web Browser, Android App or some other web service or applications.

Now when you provide a Facade. It will expose you the interface that your Android App (Remote Client) will use to access the server side. In this way, your android app don't have to worry about the implementation details of business logic and data processing.

Your logic for accessing and processing data may change over time but as long as your Facade Interface is same you client won't have to worry about anything, which is the benefit of facade. Moreover if tomorrow if you want to develop the app in windows or iPhone you can use the same Facade interface to access your system w/o writing a single new line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now i want to know (i've asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131883/how-to-implement-session-facade-or-others-patterns-without-ejb/12131908#12131908) if i can implement a session facade without using ejb.
Thanks again! ;)

Comment: To implement Facade pattern its not compulsory to use EJB. That's the beauty of this pattern. You can implement it using any good approach you want. However to use EJB or not will depend on how you want to implement your business layer n all.

Comment: Many thanks @Atul i was focused on the book that is very specific to EJB ;)

Answer (score 0):

Facade should provide simplified interface for server client comunication (session). So this service (facade) should agregate all important methods for this communication.

You can look at design patern [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to read more.

Comment: So is my specific application of the pattern correct?

Comment: I would probably have to see the implementaition, but your general idea is correct.

Comment: I haven't an implementation yet but i've the UML component diagram:

http://i47.tinypic.com/288bc0m.jpg Is a tiered architecture.
The first is the presentation tier, the middle is the business tier and the last is the integration tier
For the components:
AC stays for APPLICATION CONTROLLER and AS stays for APPLICATION SERVICE.
You can see the session facade on the right.